# Java - Can not find symbol ".retainAll()"

Tags: java

I am new in java, so don't be hard if my code is awful.
I want to extract the common element between two Arrays, and I found that you can use the function ".retainAll()" but when I use it, the cmd tells me that "It can not find the symbol ".retainAll()".
 Is there something wrong inmy code? How can I change it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.*

class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args)  {
     String string = "I will come and meet you at the 123woods";
     String keyword = "123woods";

     String[] string1 = string.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < string1.length; i++){
            string1[i] = string1[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
        }

     String[] string2 = keyword.split("\\s+");
     for (int i = 0; i < string2.length; i++){
            string2[i] = string2[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
        }

     String[] string3 = string1.retainAll(string2);



     Boolean found = Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")).contains(keyword);
     if(found){
      System.out.println("Keyword matched the string");
      System.out.println(string3);

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: `retainAll()` is a method of `Collection`. An array is not a `Collection`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a semicolon to end the following line:
`String[] string2 = keyword.split("\\s+")`.
That's why the compiler produces the can not find symbol message.

But after all, there is no method like `retainAll()` for arrays. You may want to invoke a `Collection` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) on a simple array.

You should work with collections instead of simple arrays, if you want to use their methods.